# How to request discord https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/login from website script

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to send my login request to discord from my websie which I have shared below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hCaptcha Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="****"></div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script src="https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
        const url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/login";

        function getCaptchaResponse() {
            return window.hcaptcha.getResponse();
        }

        document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const payload = {
                email: document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value,
                password: document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value,
                captcha_key: ["captcha-required"],
                captcha_service: "hcaptcha",
                captcha_sitekey: "???",
            };

            const headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            };

            fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(payload)
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    console.log("Login failed!");
                    console.log("Response status code:", response.status);
                    return response.text();
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                if (data) {
                    console.log("Login successful!");
                    console.log("Response JSON:", data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to send the form with completet hcaptcha but I still receive Status Code 400.

{message: "Ungültiger Formulartext", code: 50035,…}
code
:
50035
errors
:
{captcha_key: {_errors: [{code: "STRING_TYPE_CONVERT",…}]}}
captcha_key
:
{_errors: [{code: "STRING_TYPE_CONVERT",…}]}
message
:
"Ungültiger Formulartext"

Comment: Do you need to `JSON.stringify` your payload? could you try `body: payload`

Comment: If you just use body: payload without JSON.stringify() you would be sending a JavaScript object as the request body which is not the expected format for sending JSON data in an HTTP POST request. The server would likely not be able to parse the request body correctly.